# Proof that a matrix is symmetric

Tags: matrices, proof-verification

If I know that

\begin{equation}
F_i(x_1,\ldots,x_i)^T + F_i(x_1,\ldots,x_i) \geq 0
\end{equation}

can I then proof that:
\begin{equation}
2F_i = F_i + F_i^T
\end{equation}?

This last equality indicates that $F_i$ is a symmetric matrix. So is it somehow possible to use the given inequality to show that $F_i$ is a symmetric matrix?

Comment: What if $F_i(x_1,\dots,x_i)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\1&0\end{array}\right]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, trivially by example. $\begin{bmatrix}1 &1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}1 &0\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is positive semidefinite, but  $\begin{bmatrix}1 &1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is not symmetric.